# JMeter regex variable

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a regex Debug Sampler for printing the environment variable files of JMeter, system.properties etc.

Then I do a regex Extractor postprocessing as follows:
[image: regex extractor postprocessing]

Unfortunately, when I add an Response assertion for the filed regex variable ${regex} I get null in the view results tree of the run.
[image: response assertion]

How do I get the value of the regex variable apart from null?

Thanks
Gerrit

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

Using the Post-Processor > Regular Expression Extractor, it is simple to extract any portion of the response.

Since JMeter 2.4, the listener **View Results Tree** include a RegExp Tester to test regular expressions directly on sampler response data

---

You can use the following:

```
Reference Name: regex
Regular Expression: ([A-Z][a-z])
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
```

The template is used to create a string from the matches found. This is an arbitrary string with special elements to refer to groups within the regular expression. So to refer to group 1, you would use `$1$`..

Use the corresponding *variable* to access the match. `${regex}`

The *variables* are set as follows:

```
regex_matchNr - Number of matches found, possibly 0
regex_n       - (n = 1, 2, etc..) Generated by the template
regex_n_gm    - (m = 0, 1, 2) Groups for the match (n) 
regex         - By itself it is always set to the default value
regex_gn      - Not set at all
```

Comment: yes, thank you! I think this is the way it should work, too. But my response assertion, now for the variable ${regex_1}, is still null...

Comment: no `${regex}` `${regex_1}` and `${FOO}` are working properly. I am stuck.

Comment: @Leder see updated edit. Perhaps your missing something, this works for me.